# How to customize display report using crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, rpt

[Target Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSnZK.jpg)

In my crystal report I want to display like this. In my query the `vehicleplateno` there are the same value but in my crystal report it repeats the value.

What I need in my current output are

1. How can I group the same Plate no? the purple circle
2. and also how to compute the amount of the same `vehicleplateno`. the red circle

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8or8.jpg)

[Crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k937Z.jpg)

How can I align this? the Plate No. and Vehicle is in groupheadersection andthe VMR No. and Amount is in the section3(details) in crystal report designer.
[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M5ck.png)
[output design viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLsfe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Report > Group Expert**. Then Select the first field that you want to use to group data.   Click the arrow button that's pointing toward the Group By section to move it to that section as shown below.

[image]

Then click OK.
Refer this too
[Crystal report grouping](https://www.universalclass.com/articles/computers/how-to-group-data-in-crystal-reports.htm#:%7E:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20go%20to,use%20for%20grouping%20your%20data.)

Comment: Oh thanks, that's work right now I want to align the group header to Details? is that possible?

Comment: You can align the headers with details. Your question is not clear to me. I'll attach a document to my answer so that you can get more info.

Comment: I updated my question and added new photo. Hoping to help me  @Sachintha

Comment: Have you tried moving the data labels of the report design view ?

Comment: I put the `vehicleplateno` and `vehicle` to GroupHeaderSection1  section then `VMR no` and `Amount` is in the Section3 (Details) section.

Comment: I added my output design viewer to see what I'm trying to say, Thanks